# In-App purchases appStoreReceiptURL is empty

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

2 months ago I made auto-renewable purchases in my app and everything was fine with sandbox. But now I can't get receipt with NSBundle.mainBundle().appStoreReceiptURL this path doesn't exit. How can it be? There was receipt 2 month ago(or less). Help me, please! This is how I get receipt(swift 2) -

```
static func receipt() -> String {
    print("RECEPT URL", NSBundle.mainBundle().appStoreReceiptURL)

    guard let receiptUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().appStoreReceiptURL, let receiptPath = receiptUrl.path else { return "" }
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(receiptPath){
        var receiptData: NSData?
        do {
            receiptData = try NSData(contentsOfURL: receiptUrl, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedAlways)
        }
        catch {
            print("ERROR: " )
        }

        //guard let receiptData = NSData(contentsOfURL: receiptUrl) else { return "" }
        if let receiptString = receiptData?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0)) {
            print("REC", receipt, receiptString)

            return receiptString
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to docs, [appStoreReceiptURL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1407276-appstorereceipturl) may or may not point to file with the receipt. You can request for receipt refresh using [SKReceiptRefreshRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skreceiptrefreshrequest).

Comment: I made it, but nothing happened. Receipt is still nil.